# Django model idea for storing visitor statistics

Tags: django, google-analytics, model, analytics

I am currently looking to build a Django module for providing a website with google-analytics like data, but without google-analytics.

So I would want to process/record requests somehow before being able to display cumulative statistics regarding my visitors.

1. total number of views
2. total number of mobile views
3. total number of desktop views
4. visitors from north america
5. visitors from south america
6. ...

Currently what I have in mind amounts to something of an incredibly large enumeration

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    date   = models.DateTimeField() # statistics are partitioned chronologically

    total  = models.IntegerField()  # number of total views
    mobile = models.IntegerField()  # number of mobile views
    ...
    from_na = models.IntegerField() # from north america
    from_sa = models.IntegerField() # from south america
    ...
```

However, as one might imagine, this would be extremely un-extensible as any future desire for an additional field of interest (e.g. visitors from antartica) would require modifying the schema of an entire database table.

**Primarily, I am interested in storage-usage vs extensibility.**

For example, if I wanted to be extremely extensible, I could just save a tuple for every request storing all relevant base information (user-agent, ip-address, etc) and later derive all desired statistics through clever use of aggregations. 
(Although I'm not quite sure if this is even feasible)

And if I wanted to be extremely storage-usage friendly, I could just go with incredibly large enumerations of integer fields. (Although this again goes back to our original problem of being hard to extend functionality to)

**I was wondering if anyone could share any insight into alternative implementations of Django models for an application with the intended purpose of recording and displaying visitor statistics to a website**

What does google analytics do?